# redshift use regex expression with case when statement

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift, case, regular-language

I am trying to use `regex` expression with `case when` statement like this:

```
select 'https://www8.asdf.ac.th/studyphp/frontend/runtime/id/dfe135.php?3ca6d7=maya-pirati' as url, 
case when url ~ 'www[0-9]+\\.' then split_part(SPLIT_PART(url,'www[0-9]+\\.',2),'/',1)
else split_part(url, '/', 1)
end
```

But this gives `empty` string as `split_part`.

Before this, I used to add literal string like:

```
case when url like '%www8%'... split_part(split_part(url, 'www8.', 2), '/', 1)
```

And this used to work.

Is there any other way I can achieve with regular expression in this statement?